# Getting the results of a query for each day in the past 30 days

Tags: mysql, sql

Below is a query I run to extract some data in the past 24 hours.

```
SELECT
    s.symbol,
    count(cs.symbol_id) AS mentions
FROM symbols s
LEFT JOIN comments_symbols cs ON cs.symbol_id = s.id
LEFT JOIN comments c ON c.id = cs.comment_id
WHERE c.`date` > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
GROUP BY (s.symbol)
ORDER BY mentions
DESC LIMIT 15
```

However, I need 24 hour intervals of data for the past 30 days in order to show a 30-day chart.

Instead of executing this query 30 times for the each day in the past 30 days, is there an approach I can take to do it with just one query execution?

It seems executing this query 30 times per page load may not be the best way to do this, no?

I hope I explained clearly, please let me know if any details are fuzzy.

Comment: You can user GROUP BY date after selecting last 30 days data.

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me assume you have a list of dates.  If you don't want to list them out, you can generate them:

```
with recursive dates as (
      select curdate() - interval 30 day as dte
      union all
      select dte + interval 1 day
      from dates
      where dte < curdate()
     )
```

Second, the `LEFT JOIN` seems superfluous, because you are filtering the results using `LIMIT`.  However, I'll leave it in.  Use a `cross join` to generate a row for each day and symbol . . . then aggregate:

```
SELECT s.symbol, COUNT(cs.symbol_id) AS mentions
FROM dates d CROSS JOIN
     symbols s LEFT JOIN
     comments_symbols cs
     ON cs.symbol_id = s.id LEFT JOIN
     comments c
     ON c.id = cs.comment_id AND
        c.date >= d.dte AND
        c.date < d.date + interval 1 day
GROUP BY d.dte, s.symbol
ORDER BY d.dte, mentions DESC
```

Finally, to get 15 per day, let's put that into a CTE and use window functions:

```
WITH sm as (
      SELECT d.dte, s.symbol, COUNT(cs.symbol_id) AS mentions
      FROM dates d CROSS JOIN
           symbols s LEFT JOIN
           comments_symbols cs
           ON cs.symbol_id = s.id LEFT JOIN
           comments c
           ON c.id = cs.comment_id AND
              c.date >= d.dte AND
              c.date < d.date + interval 1 day
      GROUP BY d.dte, s.symbol
     )
SELECT cs.*
FROM (SELECT cs.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY dte ORDER BY mentions DESC) as seqnum
      FROM cs
     ) cs
WHERE seqnum <= 15;
ORDER BY dte, mentions DESC;
```